# How to add "CC" in the automatic Google spreadsheet reminder?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having a sheet which is having 12 columns as 0 1 2 3 4 ----- 12.

The values are as follows.

```
0 - numbers,
1 - Subject, 
2 - 1st owner mail id, 
3 - 2nd owner mail id, 
4 - Status, 
5 - Date, .... etc.
```

I wrote some code which is automatically sending Emails when the value at `5 - Date` is considered as final date.

On exceeding it will give reminder emails/reminder as per the trigger.

The code is as follows:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName("BiWeekly/Monthly Reports");
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var numOfColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 12);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  var status = "";

  var i = 0;
  for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[2];
    var message = row[1];

    status = new Date();

    if (status < status) {
      var subject = "ETA follow up with";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    };
  };
};
```

**Question**

How can I add a function, named `CC`, which should contain the **1st owner mail id**, as per the above condition.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly (hopefully!) you just need this:

```
ccEmailAddress = row[3]

MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {cc: ccEmailAddress});
```

For more information check the documentation here - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)

Comment: Yes Erinan, you got it. the code is working. But an exceptional error I am getting. Saying "Failed to send email: no recipient (line 24, file "New_reminders")".. Is der any solution for this?

Comment: It's hard to debug without seeing your data. My gut feeling is that some of the email address cells are empty or that the size of your data range is too big. Can you not show a screenshot of your data after obfuscating/replacing the sensitive data?

Answer (score 0):

I just modified in the last part of this code. The users are getting the reminder mails. But One error is showing at the time of executing the code. It is showing **Failed to send email: no recipient (line 24, file "New_reminders"**)

```
function sendEmails() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("BiWeekly/Monthly Reports");
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var numOfColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 12);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var status = "";
  var date = "";
  var i = 0;
  for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
  var row = data[i];
  var emailAddress = row[3];
  var emailAddress1 = row[2];
  var message = row[1];
  date = new Date();
  status = row[6];
  if (status < date) {
  var subject = "ETA follow up with";
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
  cc: emailAddress1
  });
  };
  };
  };
```

Is there any way that I can run the code in 100% success?